# How to assign defined string constant to type [Typescript]

Tags: typescript

I have a predefined object:

```
const obj = {
  ONE: 'ONE',
  TWO: 'TWO'
};
```

I want to define assign the constant `obj.ONE` to a new type like this:

```
type TOne = obj.ONE
```

I get the following warning:
`Cannot find namespace 'obj'.` or `'ONE' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.` if I don't put the strings inside an object. Is there a fix around this to allow me to assign a predefined string to a type?

Comment: You're looking for `typeof obj.ONE`

Comment: @CertainPerformance that would assign the type `string` to TOne, but I want type `"ONE"`

Comment: If you can't control how the object is defined, then you can't get to `'ONE'` due to automatic type widening

Comment: I understand. Is there a way to control the object so that `typeof obj.ONE` will return `"ONE"` ?

Comment: If you can control where it's defined, declare the object `as const`, or `as 'ONE'` in the property definition. Otherwise, you're out of luck

Comment: Yes, I can control the definition. I have already defined the object `as const`, and I gave it a try defining `ONE: 'ONE' as 'ONE'`. But the type still shows as `string`, unfortunately.

Comment: Works fine here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGB5AcgKIBcMA5AYWQDTYwAqA6rqWU7mZgL4wCGEMUJCgBuTJigBPAA4BTGAA1UMKXJAAzOEgB0lEUA

Comment: I tried `as const`, it appears to work perfectly now. Thank you very much. If you would like to put your answer down I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, to extract the value of a property from an object, you can use `typeof`, eg:

```
const TOne = typeof obj.ONE;
```

But, in object literals, Typescript automatically widens the types of the values by default, unfortunately, so

```
const obj = {
  ONE: 'ONE',
  TWO: 'TWO'
};
```

results in an `obj` of type

```
{
  ONE: string;
  TWO: string;
}
```

The `'ONE'` string type is lost. You can avoid the type widening by declaring the object `as const`, or by declaring the property `as const` or `as 'ONE'`:

```
const obj = {
  ONE: 'ONE',
  TWO: 'TWO'
} as const;
```

```
const obj = {
  ONE: 'ONE' as 'ONE',
  TWO: 'TWO'
};
```